# Using g++ and subprocess in Python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, g++, subprocess

Any ideas on how to run thus command in python via `check_output`?

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o output code.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

This are the attempts I've tried without success:

```
code_cpp = <path to code.cpp>
check_output(['g++', '-ggdb', 'pkg-config', '--cflags', 'opencv', '-o', 'output', code_cpp, 'pkg-config', '--libs',  'opencv'])

check_output(['g++', '-ggdb', '`', 'pkg-config', '--cflags', 'opencv', '`', '-o', 'output', code_cpp, '`', 'pkg-config', '--libs',  'opencv', '`'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using shell features you should call as shell command:

```
code_cpp = <path to code.cpp>
cmd = 'g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o output {0} `pkg-config --libs opencv`'.format(code_cpp)
check_output(['bash','-c',cmd])
```